# Existing controls Disappears on adding new controls dynamically in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I am a beginner and learning to develop cross-platform application in xamarin forms in visual Studio 2015. I have a **stackLayout** in which elements like Label and button "OK" are present. I want to add a new label below "OK" button on click of OK "button" **(Dynamically adding control)**.
But when i do so the new button **adds** the label but the **existing controls**(label and button) **disappears** to somewhere. Am i going wrong somewhere ?.Please help me sort this problem.[The attached image shows my output][1]

Image : [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLlQN.jpg

This below is the code of my App.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Practise
{
    public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page2 ()
        {enter code here
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        private void OkButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var layout = new StackLayout();
            var label = new Label { Text = "This is a new label.", TextColor = Color.FromHex("#77d065"), FontSize = 30, TranslationY = 30 };
            this.Content = layout;
            layout.Children.Add(label);
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Practise.Page2" Title="App1">
    <StackLayout>

            <Label Text="Click to add new label" HorizontalOptions="Center"  TranslationY="45" FontSize="Medium"/>
        <Button x:Name="OkButton" Clicked="OkButton_Clicked"  Text="Ok" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="100" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="45" TranslationY="60"/>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a ContentPage only has a single Content element.  This code creates a NEW StackLayout and replaces the existing Content (defined in the XAML) with new content.

```
var layout = new StackLayout();
var label = new Label { Text = "This is a new label.", TextColor = Color.FromHex("#77d065"), FontSize = 30, TranslationY = 30 };
this.Content = layout;
layout.Children.Add(label);
```

to add additional content to the existing layout (you will need to add `x:Name="layout"` into your XAML StackLayout declaration)

```
var label = new Label { Text = "This is a new label.", TextColor = Color.FromHex("#77d065"), FontSize = 30, TranslationY = 30 };
layout.Children.Add(label);
```

Comment: Thanks You Sir. Your suggestion worked very finely for me. I would also like to know whether i can have navigation page and tabbedpage together  ?. I am having three xaml pages say A.xaml, B.xaml, C.xaml. I have made A as navigation page by writing the code as MainPage = new NavigationPage(new A()); in App.cs. Now i want B and C to be tabbedpage. So i want to navigate to tabbedpage  B and C by clicking a button in page A. How can I implement this?